# Android app error when trying to connect to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-connection

Good day!

I was following this tutorial  - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiSMgy9UciI

and tried to connect my Android application to SQL Server 2005. Application should get data from database and display it in emulator. Now, I'm stuck with unknown error, when running application it displays empty screen and message "" and no errors occur in console or LogCat.

Here is my first_activity.java code:

```
public class First_activity extends Activity {

// creating the objects
Button EXECUTAR;
EditText ValorBusca;
ListView Lista;
Connection connect;
SimpleAdapter AD;

//declaring the objects
    private void declarar()
    {
        EXECUTAR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_buscar);
        ValorBusca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_buscar);
        Lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_output);
    }

//initialize objects 
private void inicializar()
{       
    declarar();
ValorBusca.setText("Select ID_pl, pl_name from Planogram_HEAD");
connect = CONN("sa", "Zxc123456", "Market", "10.0.2.2:1433");
}

//create classes
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private Connection CONN (String _user, String _pass, String _DB, String _server)
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnUrl = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ _server + ";" + "databaseName=" + _DB + ";user=" + _user + ";password=" + _pass + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnUrl);

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERROR", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("connected");
    return conn;
}


public void QuerySQL (String COMANDOSQL) {
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(COMANDOSQL);
        //configuring of simple Adapter

        List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        while(rs.next()) {
            Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
            datanum.put("A", rs.getString("ID_pl"));
            datanum.put("B", rs.getString("pl_name"));
            data.add(datanum);
        }

        String[] from = {"A", "B"};
        int[] views = {R.id.tex_title, R.id.text_content};
        AD = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.model, from, views);
        Lista.setAdapter(AD);
} catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);

    inicializar();
    EXECUTAR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
        public void onClick(View v){
            QuerySQL(ValorBusca.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Entire code is correct, I just needed to add "instance" to the URL and set ALLIP = 1433 in "SQL Server Configuration Manager".

Thanks for attention!
BR,
Makpal